# Unable to open RTSP Stream on Nexus 5

Tags: android, rtsp

I am trying to open an RTSP stream, using the code below but only get a blank screen. I am running this on a Nexus 5. I am able to open the same URL using the android VLC app. 
Here's the log:
Here's the log:
03-04 06:57:59.247   776  1004 I ActivityManager: Start proc 1875:com.vibhani.rtspexperiment/u0a180 for activity com.vibhani.rtspexperiment/com.vibhanirtsp.rtspexperiment.MainActivity
03-04 06:57:59.285  1875  1875 I art     : Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-04 06:57:59.347  1875  1875 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.vibhani.rtspexperiment-2/lib/arm
03-04 06:57:59.367   892   892 W Binder_4: type=1400 audit(0.0:61294): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[4550745]" dev="sockfs" ino=4550745 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
03-04 06:57:59.367   892   892 W Binder_4: type=1400 audit(0.0:61295): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[4550745]" dev="sockfs" ino=4550745 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
03-04 06:57:59.367   892   892 W Binder_4: type=1400 audit(0.0:61296): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[4550747]" dev="sockfs" ino=4550747 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
03-04 06:57:59.374  1875  1908 D OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-04 06:57:59.367   892   892 W Binder_4: type=1400 audit(0.0:61297): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[4550747]" dev="sockfs" ino=4550747 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tcontext=u:r:surfaceflinger:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
03-04 06:57:59.377  5028  5028 W Binder_10: type=1400 audit(0.0:61298): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[4550751]" dev="sockfs" ino=4550751 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
03-04 06:57:59.377  5028  5028 W Binder_10: type=1400 audit(0.0:61299): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[4550751]" dev="sockfs" ino=4550751 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
03-04 06:57:59.403  1875  1908 I Adreno-EGL: : QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
03-04 06:57:59.405  1875  1908 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-04 06:57:59.436  1875  1875 W MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: rtsp://xxxxx:xxxx@192.168.1.102/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0
03-04 06:57:59.438   202  1917 D NuPlayer: onSetVideoSurface(0xb4905100, no video decoder)
03-04 06:57:59.439   202  1917 D NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xb44ad720), (200, 701, 0)
03-04 06:57:59.439  1875  1894 W MediaPlayer: info/warning (701, 0)
03-04 06:57:59.463   202  1918 I RTSPSource: connection request completed with result 0 (Success)
03-04 06:57:59.472   776   798 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.vibhani.rtspexperiment/com.vibhanirtsp.rtspexperiment.MainActivity: +236ms
03-04 06:57:59.478   202  1918 I ARTSPConnection: status: RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
03-04 06:57:59.479   202  1918 I ARTSPConnection: re-sending request with authentication headers...
03-04 06:57:59.467  5028  5028 W Binder_10: type=1400 audit(0.0:61300): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[4550753]" dev="sockfs" ino=4550753 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
03-04 06:57:59.467  5028  5028 W Binder_10: type=1400 audit(0.0:61301): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[4550753]" dev="sockfs" ino=4550753 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
03-04 06:57:59.467   944   944 W Binder_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:61302): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[4550752]" dev="sockfs" ino=4550752 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
03-04 06:57:59.486  1555  1555 I GoogleInputMethod: onFinishInput() : Dummy InputConnection bound
03-04 06:57:59.486  1555  1555 I GoogleInputMethod: onStartInput() : Dummy InputConnection bound
03-04 06:57:59.467   944   944 W Binder_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:61303): avc: denied { ioctl } for path="socket:[4550752]" dev="sockfs" ino=4550752 ioctlcmd=7704 scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
03-04 06:57:59.512   202  1918 I ARTSPConnection: status: RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
03-04 06:57:59.513   202  1918 I RTSPSource: DESCRIBE completed with result 0 (Success)
03-04 06:57:59.516   202  1917 D NuPlayerDriver: notifyListener_l(0xb44ad720), (100, 1, -2147483648)
03-04 06:57:59.516  1875  1895 E MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
03-04 06:57:59.517  1875  1875 E MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    final static String USERNAME = "xxxxx";
    final static String PASSWORD = "xxxxx";
    final static String RTSP_URL = "rtsp://xxxxx:xxxxx@192.168.1.102/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0";

    private MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer;
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set up a full-screen black window.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.black);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Configure the view that renders live video.
        SurfaceView surfaceView =
                (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        _surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        _surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(320, 240);
    }

    /*
SurfaceHolder.Callback
*/

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(
            SurfaceHolder sh, int f, int w, int h) {}

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder sh) {
        _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        _mediaPlayer.setDisplay(_surfaceHolder);

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Map<String, String> headers = getRtspHeaders();
        Uri source = Uri.parse(RTSP_URL);

        try {
            // Specify the IP camera's URL and auth headers.
            _mediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, source, headers);

            // Begin the process of setting up a video stream.
            _mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            _mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder sh) {
        _mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    private Map<String, String> getRtspHeaders() {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String basicAuthValue = getBasicAuthValue(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        headers.put("Authorization", basicAuthValue);
        return headers;
    }

    private String getBasicAuthValue(String usr, String pwd) {
        String credentials = usr + ":" + pwd;
        int flags = Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_WRAP;
        byte[] bytes = credentials.getBytes();
        return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(bytes, flags);
    }

    /*
MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener
*/
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        _mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe these answers can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25443453/192373 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42575336/192373

Comment: I have included the credentials as suggested in these - doesn't work. Haven't tried with VLC library yet.